# How to set different cursors for an element and it's border

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to set different cursors for an element and it's border ?
PSEUDO elements ? is there a way ? 
Note: Yes it can be done via JS, i was looking for a way using pure CSS with a single element.

Comment: What's that "Heading" doing there? Did you misclick the formatting tools?

Comment: Can't you use the `cursor` style attribute? You can specify something different for pseudo selectors, like `:hover` as well

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/k8GRe/

Comment: @Blender Make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 15):

It's a lot's of HTML/CSS code, but something like that will help you:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.crop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  cursor: move;
}

.crop .crop-line {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.crop:hover .crop-line {
  border-color: rgba(123,53,132,1);
}
.crop .crop-top-line {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px; /* 5px for the mouse cursor update size */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(204,31,48,1); /* 1px for the "border" size */
  cursor: n-resize;
}
.crop .crop-bottom-line {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px; /* 5px for the mouse cursor update size */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,31,48,1); /* 1px for the "border" size */
  cursor: s-resize;
}
.crop .crop-left-line {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px; /* 5px for the mouse cursor update size */
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(204,31,48,1); /* 1px for the "border" size */
  cursor: w-resize;
}
.crop .crop-right-line {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px; /* 5px for the mouse cursor update size */
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(204,31,48,1); /* 1px for the "border" size */
  cursor: e-resize;
}
.crop .crop-corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  background: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.crop .crop-top-left-corner {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}
.crop .crop-top-right-corner {
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}
.crop .crop-bottom-left-corner {
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}
.crop .crop-bottom-right-corner {
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}
.crop:hover .crop-corner {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="crop">
   <div class="crop-line crop-top-line"></div>
   <div class="crop-line crop-right-line"></div>
   <div class="crop-line crop-bottom-line"></div>
   <div class="crop-line crop-left-line"></div>

   <div class="crop-corner crop-top-left-corner"></div>
   <div class="crop-corner crop-top-right-corner"></div>
   <div class="crop-corner crop-bottom-right-corner"></div>
   <div class="crop-corner crop-bottom-left-corner"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the `cursor` property affects the shape of the pointer (oddly called “cursor” in CSS) in the element’s entire area, including border, there is no direct way to do this.

You could use JavaScript to determine the content area of the element and then modify the DOM so that an additional element for the content is introduced, and then you can set different “cursor” for the inner element and the outer element.

However, it is normally simpler to do such things in markup, and you won’t then need JavaScript at all for this:

```
<div id=foo><div id=foo-content>...</div></div>
```

Now you can set a border on `#foo` and set `cursor` on both elements. The “cursor” set on `#foo` will then be applied to the border only.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYUeM/)

Comment: Yes, thank you, but ours is a DOM intensive app, hence was looking to achieve it via a single element sans Javascript. i have edited the title to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

`:before` and `:after` seem to allow the *cursor* property in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLZZG/, but really you will be better off wrapping the element and giving the wrapper a cursor.

**Update:** At the time of this edit (6 Apr 2015) this is now working in Chrome.